# Curl Get Request Removes spaces

Tags: php, curl

Server data as viewed through a browser:

> Ab91231 B923244 C9ds23911 D300231

```
  $curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.test.com/stuff',
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => ''
        ));

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Send the request & save response to $resp
        if(!curl_exec($curl)){
            die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
        }
// Close request to clear up some resources
        curl_close($curl);


        print_r($resp);
```

printing the curl response I get :

> Ab91231B923244C9ds23911D300231

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: str_replace(' ', '', $resp); ?

Comment: no @RakeshSharma the OP didn't want a string replacement, the problem is, when the url is seen on the browser, the response has spaces, when it is accessed thru curl, the spaces between the strings are truncated

Comment: @ghost exactly that is the problem

Comment: @Undermine2k yes i understood, do you have a sample that everybody can test why its happening? from this end, seems we can only guess

Comment: @ghost here is the url im curling https://mtgolibrary.com/api/buddy_credit_list?buddy=teamstoge&password=a_random_password

Comment: hello @Undermine2k i have seen the response, i don't understand, that example string that you gave, i cant find that on the response, and there is no spaces (using browser), only underscores and newlines

Answer (score 0):

This is because of one or both of these reasons:

1. The server-side code detects if a browser or curl ask for the resource and sends back the data differently depending on who asks.
2. The browser-side has something that changes the formatting of what you see, like javascript.